# AutoMapper - how to use custom value resolver inside custom type converter

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, typeconverter, resolver

How can I use custom value resolvers inside custom type converter?
Currently, it seems to me hard to achieve. Do you know a way to how I can use this class?

---

**Person converter**

```
class PersonConverter : ITypeConverter<PersonData, Person>
{
    public Person Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var personData = context.SourceValue as PersonData;
        if (personData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var person = new Person
        {
            Name = personData.Name
        };
        //person.Dic = // use here my DictionaryResolver

        return person;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary Dic { get; set; }
}

class PersonData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DicId { get; set; }
}

class Dictionary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Value resolver**

```
class DictionaryResolver : ValueResolver<int, Dictionary>
{
    protected override Dictionary ResolveCore(int source)
    {
        // do something
        return new Dictionary
        {
            Id = source,
            Name = "Name"
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Custom value resolvers are designed for overriding the mapping of a specific member, when AutoMapper is going to map the objects:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonData, Person>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Dic, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DictionaryResolver>());
```

However, when you use a custom type resolver, this takes complete control of the mapping: there is no way of customising how one particular member is mapped:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TPersonData, Person>().ConvertUsing(PersonConverter ); // No ForMember here.
```

However, given that you *have* complete control during type conversion, there is nothing stopping you from reusing the value converter, you just have to reference it specifically: however you will have to add a public  method which returns the protected method `ResolveCore`:

```
class DictionaryResolver : ValueResolver<int, Dictionary>
{
    public Dictionary Resolve(int source)
    {
        return ResolveCore(source);
    }

    protected override Dictionary ResolveCore(int source)
    {
        // do something
        return new Dictionary
        {
            Id = source,
            Name = "Name"
        };
    }
}
```

Then during type conversion you call it to resolve that property:

```
var person = new Person
    {
        Name = personData.Name
    };

DictionaryResolver resolver = new DictionaryResolver();
person.Dic = resolver.Resolve(personData.IntValue); // whatever value you use
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a great answer

Comment: It looks like the question is 7 years old. The Docs right now, all seem to be centered around `IValueResolver<Source, Destination, int>` nowadays. Given the same question, how do you do this with IValueResolver?

Comment: @SebastianPatten you should ask a new question!

Comment: Its still the same question lol. Just the answer has expired

Comment: Ok, but that’s the way this site works.